# Is it possible in JEST to test a specific part of a method to check on a specific result

Tags: javascript, jestjs, integration-testing

I have a class with a method for which I'm building a test with JEST.
The below snippet shows what I want to test.

I would like to test for example `c5` and I would like to check there what will happen if the `length === 0` or `length === 2` as the specific result should happen only with `length === 1`

I already built tests for other cases as follow

```
test('C1 - is default, same country, active', async () => {
    try {
      const service = serviceWithDAO({ sites: Data.mock});
      const defaultSite = await service.getDefaultSite({ studyId: 'DEFAULT1', locale: 'us_ES'});
      console.log('C1', defaultSite);
      expect(defaultSite.default).toBeTruthy();
      expect(defaultSite.countryCode).toEqual('es');
      expect(defaultSite.status).toEqual('ACTIVE');
      expect(defaultSite.siteId).toEqual('site 1');
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
```

The above test passes as expected but I have doubts about how can I test what result to expect in case 5 as described that case should have `length === 1` and I want to test a fail case.

below is the method and I'm interested in how should I do a test for `C5` case

```
class SiteService extends ServiceBase {
 getDefaultSite({ studyId, locale }) {
    return this.withDAO(async ({ sites }) => {
      const sitesStudy = await sites.select({ studyId });
      if (!sitesStudy || !sitesStudy.length) return undefined;
      const countryCode = locale.substr(3, 4).toLowerCase();

      const c1 = sitesStudy.filter(
        site =>
          site.default &&
          site.countryCode === countryCode &&
          site.status === 'ACTIVE'
      );
      console.log('C1', c1);
      if (c1[0]) return c1[0];

      const c2 = sitesStudy.filter(
        site =>
          site.default &&
          site.countryCode === countryCode &&
          site.status === 'INACTIVE'
      );
      console.log('C2', c2);
      if (c2[0]) return c2[0];

      console.log(
        sitesStudy.filter(
          site =>
            site.default &&
            site.countryCode !== countryCode &&
            site.status === 'ACTIVE'
        ),
        countryCode
      );

      const c3 = sitesStudy.filter(
        site =>
          site.default &&
          site.countryCode !== countryCode &&
          site.status === 'ACTIVE'
      );
      console.log('C3', c3);
      if (c3[0]) return c3[0];

      const c4 = sitesStudy.filter(
        site =>
          site.default &&
          site.countryCode !== countryCode &&
          site.status === 'INACTIVE'
      );
      console.log('C4', c4);
      if (c4[0]) return c4[0];

      const c5 = sitesStudy.filter(site => site.status === 'ACTIVE');
      console.log('C5', c5);

      if (c5.length === 1) return c5[0];

      return null;
    });
  }
}
```

Service base

```
function ServiceBase(ctx) {
  let key;
  let value;
  for ([key, value] of Object.entries(ctx)) {
    this[key] = value;
  }
}

ServiceBase.prototype.constructor = ServiceBase;
module.exports = ServiceBase;
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You need to set the conditions such that no preceding return is reached. But without a [mre] it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know how to do it. can you show me an example or point me to a similar example so maybe I will be able to show an example my self. Right now I can do a test as I did for C1 in my post but how to make it more specific for C5.
I would like to see `const c5` to fail with the failing cases. I have no idea how to proceed without an example.

Comment: We can't see `ServiceBase`, and it's not clear what your specific problem is. Also you shouldn't catch errors in tests; errors should *fail* the test, unless explicitly expected. But you don't test a specific part of a method, you test the whole method, and set the conditions such that the relevant part is reached.

Comment: My specific problem is that const c5 I want to check result directly there to see that c5 do not give anything out when we have length === 0 or 2 when we do not have length === 1 
Service base I will add in my post